# How to JOIN a Sub-Query using LINQ

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to Entity Framework and LINQ and am struggling to "convert" my SQL query to its syntax.

Given is a table that contains production orders with `OrderNumber`, `Quantity`, `Material` etc. as columns. Additionally there is a column `Timestamp`.

If the quantity of an order would be updated, this results in a completely new entry in the table where all values would be the same as a previous row except for `Timestamp` (indicating the time of the change) and `Quantity` (containing the new value). Thus allowing me to have a "history" of an order.

Selecting only the latest version of a specific order using SQL could look like this:

```sql
SELECT p1.*
FROM dbo.ProductionOrders as p1
  JOIN (SELECT OrderNumber, MAX(Timestamp) as Timestamp FROM dbo.ProductionOrders GROUP BY OrderNumber) as p2
    on p1.OrderNumber = p2.OrderNumber and p1.Timestamp = p2.Timestamp
WHERE p1.OrderNumber = 'order-182736'
```

The same functionality I got done in my C# code like this:

```cs
var productionOrder = _db.ProductionOrders.Where(po => po.OrderNumber == "order-182736")
                                          .OrderByDescending(po => po.Timestamp)
                                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

Where I am lost is when I want to get multiple rows. For example all orders for a specific material. Using SQL I only have to adjust the `WHERE` condition:

```sql
SELECT p1.*
FROM dbo.ProductionOrders as p1
  JOIN (SELECT OrderNumber, MAX(Timestamp) as Timestamp FROM dbo.ProductionOrders GROUP BY OrderNumber) as p2
    on p1.OrderNumber = p2.OrderNumber and p1.Timestamp = p2.Timestamp
WHERE p1.Material = 42
```

The examples I found for `JOIN` using LINQ don't operate on sub-queries (my main source is [microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netcore-3.1))

How can I get all latest "versions" of orders for a specific material using LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it the exact same way as in SQL.  `_db.ProductionOrders` in LINQ to Entities represents the `dbo.ProductionOrders` in SQL, and you can use it in both top and subquery level:

```cs
var query = _db.ProductionOrders
    .Join(_db.ProductionOrders
        .GroupBy(p2 => new { p2.OrderNumber })
        .Select(g => new { g.Key.OrderNumber, Timestamp = g.Max(e => e.Timestamp) }), // subquery
        p1 => new { p1.OrderNumber, p1.Timestamp }, p2 => p2, // join condition
        (p1, p2) => p1) // result selector (p1.*)
    .Where(p1 => p1.Material == 42);
```

(Note: Not sure where `Label` is coming from in your SQL queries, so using `OrderNumber` instead).

or if you prefer, the same in LINQ query syntax:

```cs
var query =
    from p1 in _db.ProductionOrders
    join p2 in (from p2 in _db.ProductionOrders
                group p2 by new { p2.OrderNumber }) into g
                select new { g.Key.OrderNumber, Timestamp = g.Max(p2 => p2.Timestamp) })
    on new { p1.OrderNumber, p1.Timestamp } equals p2
    where p1.Material == 42
    select p1;
```

Comment: `Label` was still there because of some copy&paste errors I made, I changed the OP. I need some time to wrap my head around LINQ...